# Why does an INSERT take time when using subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 INSERT INTO TableA
    SELECT 
       x,
       y,
       z      
          FROM TableB
            WHERE x IN 
                     (select DISTINCT x
                           FROM TableC
                               WHERE x NOT IN 
                                             (SELECT DISTINCT x from TableD)
                     )
```

This query takes forever and it doesn't complete.

When I run the each select query it works fine but when I run it all it takes forever? Can you see the reason?

Comment: Have you looked at your execution plan when you run your whole select?

Comment: "not in" tends to be slow.

Comment: sorry to say it but haven't heard of execution plan before? can you guide me on that please? @Paddy

Comment: When IN / NOT IN sub-select, there's really no need for DISTINCT in the sub-select. (Probably optimized away anyway.) But see what happens if you remove the the DISTINCT's.

Comment: In your SSMS execute your query and click on "Query" menu and select "Display Estimated execution plan" it will help to see which part takes time to be executed.

Comment: I have no glue why but adding DISTINCT TOP 1000 in the first select statement solves the problem even the return number of rows lest than 1000. Thanks

Comment: @akdurmus - your solution would probably indicate that there are issues with potentially missing or out of date indexes being used in this query, resulting in radically different estimates of the cardinality versus actual.  If you are going to run this a lot, then you should look at your table indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
insert into TableA
select b.*
from TableB b               --with(nolock)
left outer join TableC c    --with(nolock)
on b.x = c.x
left outer join TableD d    --with(nolock)
on c.x = d.x
where c.x is not null and d.x is null
```

if it is also running infinite then uncomment `with(nolock)` and try again. if it does not work then check estimated execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to look at the execution plan for the query - it might tell you where the bottlenecks are or if there are missing indexes that would significantly speed up your query - I think this is likely as your query is simple so I don't see why it would take so long;

[image]

I think you could also restructure you query so that it uses Joins instead of the not in - it would help if i knew the data to see if this produced the same results, But i think it should;

```
    SELECT  B.x,
        B.y,
        B.Z
FROM TableB B 
INNER JOIN --where in
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT x
        FROM TableC c 
        LEFT JOIN TableD d 
            ON c.x = d.x
        WHERE d.x IS NULL -- c x not in d x 
    ) sub
on B.x = sub.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries and DISTINCT when not needed are notoriously poor for performance.  You can accomplish what you need using JOINs.

```
SELECT b.x, b.y, b.z
FROM TableB b
INNER JOIN TableC c ON c.x=b.x
LEFT JOIN TableD d ON d.x=b.x
WHERE d.x IS NULL
GROUP BY b.x, b.y, b.z  -- only if you have duplicates and need unique records
```

The INNER JOIN on TableC fixes your 1st "IN", then the LEFT JOIN and d.x IS NULL fixes your "NOT IN" clause.

Lastly, make sure that you have indexes on the "x" column in each table.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TableB_X ON TableB (X);
CREATE INDEX IX_TableC_X ON TableC (X);
CREATE INDEX IX_TableD_X ON TableD (X);
```